# Asymptotics of eigenvalues of first-order self-adjoint elliptic operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, oa.operator-algebras

Let $D$ be a first-order self-adjoint elliptic operator on a closed Riemannian manifold $M$. Then $D$ has discrete spectrum in $\mathbb{R}$, and there is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(M)$ consisting of eigenfunctions of $D$.

**Question 1:** Do the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $D$ satisfy an asymptotic estimate of the form
$$|\lambda_i|\sim i^\alpha$$
for some $\alpha>0$?

Now suppose $M$ is a compact manifold with boundary, and consider the Dirichlet eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of $D$, i.e. smooth $u$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$Du=\lambda u,$$
$$u|_{\partial M}=0.$$

**Question 2:** Do we still have a decomposition of $L^2(M)$ into eigenspaces of $D$? Do the Dirichlet eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $D$ satisfy an asymptotic estimate of the form
$$|\lambda_i|\sim i^\alpha$$
for some $\alpha>0$?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand the second question correctly. Dirichlet boundary conditions on all of $\partial M$ for a first-order differential operator result in an overdetermined system (Consider for instance $i$ times the first derivative on $[0,1]$. The only function $u$ that satisfies Dirichlet boundary conditions both in $0$ and $1$ as well as the eigenvalue equation $iu' = \lambda u$ for any $\lambda$ is $u=0$.)

Comment: (By the way, I think this "overdetermined" property also implies that the resolvent set of the operator is empty, so it cannot be self-adjoint.)

Comment: This result is called Weyl's law when $D$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator, and it takes the form $\lambda_i ~ \frac{(2\pi)^2}{(\omega_d vol(M))^{2/d}} i^{\frac{2}{d}}$. It applies in the boundaryless, Neumann and Dirichlet cases. I'm sure someone has generalised it to first-order self-adjoint elliptic operators (probably with a different constant), possibly under addition conditions.

Comment: The answer to question 1 is "yes" when $D$ is a Dirac operator (see e.g. the book by Berline-Getzler-Vergne). For question 2, one can take suitable global boundary conditions instead (like Atiyah-Patodi-Singer or MIT-bag conditions). I am not so sure about more general selfadjoint elliptic operators.